# document.getElementById working for one form element but not another

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a web page that takes a 10 digit code which is split across two textboxes, 4-chars in the first textbox and 6 chars in the second.

I've been trying to implement some javascript so that when the user enters the fourth character in the first textbox the cursor jumps to the second textbox.

The page is laid out as following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCode1" onkeyup="Next()" runat="server" Width="45"    MaxLength="4"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCode2" runat="server" Width="70" MaxLength="6"/>
```

I'm using the following Javascript :

```
function Next() 
{
    var control1 = document.getElementById('<%= txtCode1.ClientID %>');
    var control2;

    if (control1.value.length == 3) 
    {
         control2 = document.getElementById['<%= txtCode2.ClientID %>'];
         control2.Focus();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the function doesn't recognise the second textbox. If I step through the Javascript has no problem is able to locate `txtCode1` and get the length but when the length hits 4 chars and it has to populate `control2` with the `getElementById()` call it sets control2 as undefined and then the control2.Focus() call throws an error.

I don't understand how the code for getting control1 and control2 is the same but this doesn't work, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, I can't believe I missed that. I bet if someone else had posted this question I'd have spotted the typo straight off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementById` is a function, not an array.

Use `()` not `[]`.

Also, in JavaScript, DOM elements have a `focus` method, not a `Focus` method.

Corrected code:

```
control2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtCode2.ClientID %>');
control2.focus();
```

Comment: Aarrrrgh. Can't believe I missed that! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In the second call, you're using square brackets instead of parentheses. In the first call, you used it correctly.

Also, as dontGoPlastic points out in the comment below, you should be using `.focus()` (lowercase) instead of `.Focus()`.

So, the code inside your second `if` block should become this:

```
control2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtCode2.ClientID %>');
control2.focus();
```

Comment: He'll also want to call `focus()`, not `Focus()`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ... And I'm on an iPad! :)

Comment: Well, I did do the copy and paste of his code. Slowed me down by that crucial amount. ;-)

Comment: @dontGoPlastic Thanks, I added that to the answer.

Comment: @bfavaretto Nice, plus-one that up, bro!

Answer (score 1):

`control2 = document.getElementById['<%= txtCode2.ClientID %>'];`

should be

```
control2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtCode2.ClientID %>');
                                  ^ paren                    ^ paren
```